# Is it safe to use calc in CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser

This data from caniuse http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc suggests that practically all browsers now support `calc` in CSS. Are there any reasons to still avoid using `calc` for consumer websites? Have any major websites started using `calc`?

Comment: Upvoted (to cancel downvote). Useful question.

Answer (score 3):

The official level is `Candidate Recommendation` for `W3C` and are descripted in draft document  [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)

Candidate Recomendation is not like Approved but is very near, so (i think) it 'a choice deeply comforted by the state of the documentation of W3C

Answer (score 3):

**IE** seems to be the problem as usual but as far as I know, the `calc` element is fairly safe to use, depending on the units you are using (c.f. 'Known issues' with `vw vh`).

About **Opera Mini**, I thought it was now using the **Chrome engine**, even on iOS (iOS Safari engine is specified for iOS on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)). Would someone have more details about this?

**EDIT:**
A very [interesting post](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) about this on CSS-Tricks by Chris Coyier.